# How to force typescript to interpret a parameter as a namespace rather than a class, when they have the same name - gRPC

Tags: typescript, vue.js, grpc, protobuf.js

Sorry for the long title...

I am implementing a simple crud little system with gRPC and typescript, my problem is: The auto generated file creates a class and a type for each parameter in my `protoFile`, for instance: UserId parameter generates a class with getUserId etc, and a namespace with the type for UserId.

The problem is that when I try to use the method in my `client`, typescript expects a class as a parameter and not the type.

so instead of `getUsersById({id: 1}, callback)`... it asks me to do `getUsersById(new UserId)`.

### user.Proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package userServicePKG;

message User {
    int32 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
    int32 age = 3;
}

message UserId {
    int32 id = 1;
}

service UserService{
    rpc getUserById (UserId) returns (User);
}
```

### UserServiceClientPb.ts (Protobuf generated) - Functions definition

```
methodInfogetUserById = new grpcWeb.AbstractClientBase.MethodInfo(
    User,
    (request: UserId) => {
      return request.serializeBinary();
    },
    User.deserializeBinary
  );

  getUserById(
    request: UserId,
    metadata: grpcWeb.Metadata | null): Promise<User>;

  getUserById(
    request: UserId,
    metadata: grpcWeb.Metadata | null,
    callback: (err: grpcWeb.Error,
               response: User) => void): grpcWeb.ClientReadableStream<User>;

  getUserById(
    request: UserId,
    metadata: grpcWeb.Metadata | null,
    callback?: (err: grpcWeb.Error,
               response: User) => void) {
    if (callback !== undefined) {
      return this.client_.rpcCall(
        new URL('/userServicePKG.UserService/getUserById', this.hostname_).toString(),
        request,
        metadata || {},
        this.methodInfogetUserById,
        callback);
    }
    return this.client_.unaryCall(
    this.hostname_ +
      '/userServicePKG.UserService/getUserById',
    request,
    metadata || {},
    this.methodInfogetUserById);
  }
```

### user_pb.d.ts (Protobuf Generated) - Define types and classes:

```
export class UserId extends jspb.Message {
  getId(): number;
  setId(value: number): UserId;

  serializeBinary(): Uint8Array;
  toObject(includeInstance?: boolean): UserId.AsObject;
  static toObject(includeInstance: boolean, msg: UserId): UserId.AsObject;
  static serializeBinaryToWriter(message: UserId, writer: jspb.BinaryWriter): void;
  static deserializeBinary(bytes: Uint8Array): UserId;
  static deserializeBinaryFromReader(message: UserId, reader: jspb.BinaryReader): UserId;
}

export namespace UserId {
  export type AsObject = {
    id: number,
  }
}
```

### Client.Vue:

```
const client = new UserServiceClient('http://localhost:5001', null, null);

let userId = { id:1 };
client.getUserById(userId, function (error: grpcWeb.Error, response: any) {
     //do something
});
```

the parameter userId fires the following error:

> Argument of type '{ id: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UserId'.
> Type '{ id: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'UserId': getId, setId, serializeBinary, toObject, and 8 more.Vetur(2345)

It looks to me that typescript is inferring that `getUserById` first parameter is of the type `Class UserId` instead of the type coming from the **namespace** `UserId`.

Is there something I can do about it? Since it was autogenerated, I feel like it should interpret correctly? Am I messing up something else? I am new to gRPC so I may be doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message `UserId` is generated as a JavaScript class. You have to provide an instance of this class, there isn't really any alternative, at least not with the code generated by protoc-gen-grpc-web.

There are some alternative code generators for TypeScript-based that do not require you to use classes. ts-proto as well as protobuf-ts use simple interfaces instead of classes to represent messages. (I am the author of protobuf-ts).

For example, protobuf-ts generates code from your user.proto that can be used like this:

```js
// gRPC-web provided by @protobuf-ts/grpcweb-transport
const transport = new GrpcWebFetchTransport("http://localhost:5001");

const client = new UserServiceClient(transport);

const {response} = await client.getUserById({id: 123});

console.log(
    response.id,
    response.name,
    response.age
);
```

I think ts-proto also got grpc-web support some time ago. Maybe give one of those a try and see if you like the generated code better.

Comment: You are correct, my problem is that I was looking into examples online that were using gRPC in other platforms and not gRPC web, if you generate the protos with gRPC web, you have to instantiate your "message" and then initiate its values through setters, and use them through getters... Thanks a lot!